# Creditscore dropped drastically

Tags: credit-score

I am new to this community and hoping to get some answers from the knowledgeable crowd here.

I have recently started using Transunion Credit monitoring. Last month my score dropped almost 80 points. But not sure how to know the factors that caused my credit score to drop. Is there any other website that anyone can suggest which closely monitors the score? I need something which can tell me on regular basis what caused the Credit score to raise or fall.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what happened in the last 30 days: new credit card, large purchase that used a lot of your credit, closed an account?

Comment: This depends on what your score was before. If you were over 700, it would take a much smaller incident to cause 80 points in loss, but if you were under 500, it'd be nearly impossible to lose 80 points in a month.

Comment: Yeah my previous score was above 700. After some research I realized that my credit utilization crossed the 30% limit. But didnt know that was the reason. There should be a website which tells you on a monthly or weekly basis how many points you gained or lost and the reason behind it.

Comment: Also any idea how long will it take to recover from a higher utilization impact. That is gaining the points back which I lost

Comment: It takes about a month from when you reduce your utilization back to a lower level

Comment: [CreditKarma](http://www.CreditKarma.com) provides you with the information you're asking for on a weekly basis. Also, it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the above comments are spot-on, and provide solid advice for what may have caused fluctuations in your credit score month-to-month. I would also suggest you take a look at your credit score from Experian and Equifax, the two other major credit bureaus in the U.S. From my experience, my TransUnion score has always been the lowest of the three, and I can also tell you that some of my peers and family members have noticed the same anomaly with TransUnion scores when receiving their annual credit report. If you notice all three credit bureaus reporting a similar drop, it likely has to do with your credit usage, perhaps a late payment, or even utilizing a higher percentage of your available credit. If TransUnion is the sole bureau to have such a swing, I would advise that you file a complaint directly with TransUnion and mention that you're considering the same with the FTC and Consumer Financial Protection Bureau (CFPB). Not kidding about that either, as I have strong reservations about the accuracy of TransUnion's credit scoring.

Answer (score 1):

Short but helpful thread. My transunion score dropped from 733 to 698 in one month... no late payments, no increase in utilization, no closing of accounts, no changes at all that I could perceive.

Except: I monitor score only via credit sesame, and they reported a NEW ADDRESS. I thought that could account for the drop. But when I checked my transunion report there was no new address posted. So that is a flag down on the field for credit sesame.

Here is a little trick I picked up while investigating the score drop. If you have already received your once a year free report, and wish to see the report again... and not pay... commence a dispute with transunion. Don't actually submit the dispute. As you go through the online steps your report will be displayed so that you can select what you are disputing. You can just print the report.

Ha ha. That was fun. I hate spending money.

Comment: There are far easier ways to get free reports nowadays - "once a year" is a thing of the distant past.  Creditkarma.com, Mint.com, etc. allow you to see your reports any time you want.